# uploaded documents not being returned in Sitecore search

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Complete Sitecore newbie here!.  I have inherited a website that uses sitecore as its CMS.  It has been reported to me that uploaded documents are not being returned in search. I have uploaded a document and run a search.  The new document was not returned in the results.  I then did an index rebuild and still it is not returned in the search results. Any pointers or guidance on how i can troubleshoot this.  The version of sitecore is 8.1

Comment: What about the existing documents? Are they returned in search?

Comment: @MarekMusielak There are some documents returned in the search

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the whole index? Does it help with new documents? Is the problem with some specific file type? Like pdf, doc?

Comment: @MarekMusielak When you say the whole index do you mean every index as there are a few custom indexes i think? The problem is with all uploaded documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i thought i would post this for anyone that has the same or similar errors.

Firstly i found that the crawler specified for the media library had been commented out by someone, however this did not fix the issue as the index also had another crawler specified.  It seems that in my version of sitecore (Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160302), there is a bug that causes only the first crawler to be used.  As the crawler for my media library was specified second, it was not being used.  It should be noted that this problem is only present on an update after a published event.  If you try to rebuild the index then both indexes will be used.

[Here is a link that explains the issue fully](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3480/issue-with-multiple-crawlers-on-solr-custom-search-index)